# How can I get the this gameid of dynamically created divs?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a specific gameId from my button with the class of .text, I've tried the code below but it seems to be giving me only undefined as an answer. I don't know if it has to do with where I have this running or something else. Any help would be greatly appreciated! This code is in a loop that appends these divs based on how many there are in JSON.

```
$('.wrapper').append('\
    <div id="'+ gameId +'" class="main-wrapper col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">\
        <div class="game-cards">\
            <div class="chart-container">\
                <canvas id="'+ homeTeam +'" width="500" height="500"></canvas>\
            </div>\
            <div class="right-info">\
                <h4>' + awayTeam + '<br>' + " @ " + '<br>' + homeTeam +'</h4>\
                <h5 id="time-channel">'+ gameDate +' @ ' + gameTime  + ' CT' + '<br>' + ' On ' + network +'</h5>\
            <div class="total-points-live">\
                <h5>Total Points Bet</h5>\
                <h5 class="total-points" id="point-total">'+ totalPoints +'</h5>\
                <p>'+ awayTeam + " " + awayLine +'</p>\
                <input class="bet-input-away" id="testBox" min="1" step="1" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" title="Numbers only" data-away-id="'+ awayId +'" data-team-type="'+ awayTeam +'" type="number" min="0" pattern="[1-9]*" name="betAmountAway" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                <p>'+ homeTeam + " " + homeLine +'</p>\
                <input class="bet-input-home" min="1" step="1" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" title="Numbers only" data-home-id="'+ homeId +'" data-team-type="'+ homeTeam +'" type="number" min="0" pattern="[1-9]*" name="betAmountHome" placeholder="Wager Amount">\
                <div class="wrap">\
                    <div id="capture" class="box">\
                         <button id="'+ gameId +'" class="text" data-button-id="'+ gameId +'">Click</button>\
                    </div>\
                    <div class="box paste"></div>\
                </div>\
                <p class="bet-button" gameid="'+ gameId +'">Click To Place Bet</p>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
    </div>\
        ');

    var self = $(this);
    var gameId = self.attr('gameid');
    var awayId = $('#' + gameId + '.text').data('button-id');

    console.log(gameId);

    console.log(awayId);

        $('.text').click(function(){
            alert('clicked');
            allowTaint: true,
            html2canvas($("#5995")[0]).then(function(canvas) {
            $("#hello").append(canvas);
            });
        });
```

Comment: What's `this` in the context of that code?

Comment: A workable example would be great and also may be worth a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: maybe is usefull to put an onclick="myFunction()" on your button?

Comment: @DavidThomas When I console.log(this);

main.js:137 Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
main.js:139 undefined
main.js:141 undefined
main.js:137 Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
main.js:139 undefined
main.js:141 undefined
main.js:137 Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
main.js:139 undefined
main.js:141 undefined
main.js:137 Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, frames: Window, …}
main.js:139 undefined
main.js:141 undefined

Comment: I'm abit confused. if you have access to gameId within the `append` why try and get it from the button and save to a variable when you have it already? Judging by your comment above, your contexts are out of place, maybe you are within a function and taking the scope of that instead of your element. Can we have full example please?

Comment: @FrancisLeigh I need the button id to be the same as the gameId because in each div the button does something different.